# img align attribute being stripped - tumblr api

Tags: html, tumblr

I am creating a new text post using tumblr's Python API, but when I check the html source for the created post it has stripped the align attribute from my img tags.

Here is a simple example of what I am running:

```
CLIENT.create_text(BLOG_URL, state='publish', body='<img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTAyMjQ3OTAxMzNeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU4MDU0NzA1MzAx._V1_SX214_.jpg" align="left" />')
```

Here is the resulting html for the post:

```
<p><img alt="image" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTAyMjQ3OTAxMzNeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU4MDU0NzA1MzAx._V1_SX214_.jpg" /></p>
```

Any clues as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Tumblr does some sanitation on any content when a post is created. I believe this is down to the content is shared amongst multiple sites.

For reference `align` is deprecated in HTML 4.01: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img